# Splitting image based dataset for YOLOv3

Tags: python, dataset, conv-neural-network, yolo

I have a question about splitting a dataset of 20k images along with their labels, the dataset is in the format of `YOLOv3` which has an image file and a `.txt` file with the same name as the image, the text file has the labels inside it.

I want to split the dataset into train/test splits, is there a way to randomly select the image and its labels .txt file with it and store it in a separate folder using `Python`?

I want to be able to split the dataset randomly. For instance, select 16k files along with label file too and store them separately in a train folder and the remaining 4k should be stored in a test folder.

This could manually be done in the file explorer by selecting the first 16k files and move them to a different folder but the split won't be random as I plan to do this over and over again for the same dataset.

Here is what the data looks like
[images and labels screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG7ud.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at following Python built-in modules

- [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)
- [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)
- [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)
- [shutill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

for manipulating files and paths in Python. Here is my code with comments that might solve your problem. It's very simple

```py
import glob
import random
import os
import shutil

# Get all paths to your images files and text files
PATH = 'path/to/dataset/'
img_paths = glob.glob(PATH+'*.jpg')
txt_paths = glob.glob(PATH+'*.txt')

# Calculate number of files for training, validation
data_size = len(img_paths)
r = 0.8
train_size = int(data_size * 0.8)

# Shuffle two list
img_txt = list(zip(img_paths, txt_paths))
random.seed(43)
random.shuffle(img_txt)
img_paths, txt_paths = zip(*img_txt)

# Now split them
train_img_paths = img_paths[:train_size]
train_txt_paths = txt_paths[:train_size]

valid_img_paths = img_paths[train_size:]
valid_txt_paths = txt_paths[train_size:]

# Move them to train, valid folders
train_folder = PATH+'train/' 
valid_folder = PATH+'valid/'
os.mkdir(train_folder)
os.mkdir(valid_folder)

def move(paths, folder):
    for p in paths:
        shutil.move(p, folder)

move(train_img_paths, train_folder)
move(train_txt_paths, train_folder)
move(valid_img_paths, valid_folder)
move(valid_txt_paths, valid_folder)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried to run this code on my folder with the image and text files but I seem to be getting an error, tried searching for this I am unable to fix it. The error is "

F:\Datasets\Splitting Datasets>python splits.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Datasets\Splitting Datasets\splits.py", line 19, in <module>
    random.shuffle(img_txt)
  File "F:\anaconda\envs\base1\lib\random.py", line 359, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len() "

Comment: Ah sorry mate, I forget to make zip object to become list. I will re-edit my answer now

Comment: Another fix to make is to fix the variable names under the comment  "#Now split them",
change the names "image_pahts" to "image_paths" for all four lines.
I changed and ran the code and it is working as it is supposed to. Thanks!

Comment: @ĐinhAnhVũ thank you for this simple effective code. I ask if I have 40 folders and I need to split them but avoid having the same file name in each folder (random.seed(43)). How do I modify this line?

Comment: @N.white For `random.seed(43)`, you can change to whatever number you want ([the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed)). The code should work with 40 folders of images I think. You can try to provide `img_paths = [`1/1.jpg`, 1/2.jpg,...]` and so on.

Comment: @ĐinhAnhVũ thanks for responding. The seed(43) gave the same sequence of files in anther folders .. I need to get different file names in each folder of 40th. Is it possible?